# how to check nil in parameters of a function that accept parameter of type method refrence

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-2010, delphi-xe4

i have  a function that accept 3 parameter as shown below

```
 harry3 = procedure ( x: T; y: U; z: V )of object;
 harry2 = procedure ( x: T ; y: U )of object;
 harry1 = procedure ( x: T )of object;

 procedure TTest<T, U, V>.Add(const a: harry1; const b: harry2; const c: harry3);
 begin
 if (a = nil ) and ( b = nil ) then   // error
 begin
      // dosomething
 end
 else  if (b = nil)   and ( c = nil  ) then  // error
 begin
    // dosomething
 end
 else  if (c = nil  ) and ( a = nil) then   // error
 begin
    // dosomething
 end
```

when i check a , b , c for nil it gives me error "**Not enough actual parameters**"

Comment: Use `not Assigned(a)` instead of `(a = nil)`. And use proper Delphi version tags. Delphi 7 is hardly the version that you used for this code.

Comment: What if the generic arguments are of types that cannot be nil? What if T is Integer? This is now maybe the third question of yours on which I've made that point. I don't think you are getting generics at all yet. I'd like to help.